# Dynamic link without a custom URL / suffix

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

In Firebase, we can use a dynamic link to redirect to another URL. For example, I can have something like https://example.com/download to redirect to my app's download page (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=some.package.name)

However, in my case, the landing page isn't ready yet and I want to redirect all visitors to https://example.com to the app download page. The problem is firebase requires you to have a short URL (suffix after the /) with every dynamic link, so I can't directly use dynamic links.

How can I accomplish such a redirection using firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [redirects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects) to achieve this. In `firebase.json` add something like:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "redirects": [{
      "source": "/",
      "destination": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=some.package.name",
      "type": 302
    }]
  }
}
```